# puppet not working with keys() and hiera_hash()

Tags: puppet

I have in hiera node variable `solr_enabled = true`. Also I have in this node list of fstab mount points like:

```
fstab_homes:
'/home1':
device: 'UUID=ac2ca97e-8bce-4774-92d7-051482253089'
'/home2':
device: 'UUID=d9daaeed-4e4e-40e9-aa6b-73632795e661'
'/home3':
device: 'UUID=21a358cf-2579-48cb-b89d-4ff43e4dd104'
'/home4':
device: 'UUID=c68041de-542a-4f72-9488-337048c41947'
'/home16':
device: 'UUID=d55eff53-3087-449b-9667-aeff49c556e7'
```

In solr.pp I want to get the first mounted home disk, create there folder and make symbolic link to /home/cpanelsolr.

For this I wrote the code `/etc/puppet/environments/testing/modules/cpanel/manifests/solr.pp`:

```
# Install SOLR - dovecot full text search plugin

class cpanel::solr(
    $solr_enable = hiera('solr_enabled',false),
    $homes = hiera_hash('fstab_homes', false),
    $homesKeys = keys($homes),
  )
{
if $solr_enable == true {
    notify{"Starting Solr Installation ${homesKeys[0]}":}
    if $homes != false and $homesKeys[0] != '/home' {
        file { "Create Solr home symlink to ${homesKeys[0]}":
           path => '/home/cpanelsolr',
           ensure => 'link',
           target => "${homesKeys[0]}/cpanelsolr",
        }
    }

    exec { 'cpanel-dovecot-solr':
        command => "/bin/bash -c 
'/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/install_dovecot_fts'",
      }
  }
}
```

But when I run this in dev node I get error:

```
root@webcloud2 [/home1]# puppet agent -t --no-use_srv_records --server=puppet.development.internal --environment=testing --tags=cpanel::solr
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
2018-08-03  6:04:54 140004666824672 [Note] libgovernor.so found
2018-08-03  6:04:54 140004666824672 [Note] All governors functions found too
2018-08-03  6:04:54 140004666824672 [Note] Governor connected
2018-08-03  6:04:54 140004666824672 [Note] All governors lve functions found too
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: keys(): Requires hash to work with at 
/etc/puppet/environments/testing/modules/cpanel/manifests/solr.pp:6 on node webcloud2.development.internal
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least two problems there.

First problem is `$home` won't be set at all in that context. You would need to rewrite as:

```
class cpanel::solr(
    $solr_enable = hiera('solr_enabled',false),
    $homes = hiera_hash('fstab_homes', false),
  )
{
  $homes_keys = keys($homes)
  ...
}
```

Second problem is that your YAML isn't correctly indented, so `fstab_homes` would not actually return a Hash. It should be:

```
fstab_homes:
  '/home1':
    device: 'UUID=ac2ca97e-8bce-4774-92d7-051482253089'
  '/home2':
    device: 'UUID=d9daaeed-4e4e-40e9-aa6b-73632795e661'
  '/home3':
    device: 'UUID=21a358cf-2579-48cb-b89d-4ff43e4dd104'
  '/home4':
    device: 'UUID=c68041de-542a-4f72-9488-337048c41947'
  '/home16':
    device: 'UUID=d55eff53-3087-449b-9667-aeff49c556e7'
```

Finally, be aware that use of `camelCase` in parameter names in Puppet can cause you issues in some contexts, so best to use `snake_case`.

Comment: As for node's YAML, all good, all spaces are correct. As for keys, the problem is still persists and finished with error:  Error 400 on SERVER: can't convert nil into Hash at /etc/puppet/environments/testing/modules/fstab/manifests/mount.pp:7 on node webcloud2.development.internal

Comment: Well that's a different error because that's an issue inside your mount.pp file, which I can't see.